# Given a boolen hash function (based on XOR), find the $n^{th}$ key for a specific hash.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, functions, cryptography, hash-function

A boolen hash function is given that takes a hexadecimal key as input and returns the hash for that key (hash can be only 0 or 1). The hash function is based on XORing bits of the key.

For example, an sample hash function in C would be written like this

`/* This hash function calculates hash based on XORing bits 0,1,3,4 of the key */
 bool hash_function(uint64_t key) {
    bool bit0 = (key >> 0) & 0x1;
    bool bit1 = (key >> 1) & 0x1;
    bool bit3 = (key >> 3) & 0x1;
    bool bit4 = (key >> 4) & 0x1;
    return bit0 ^ bit1 ^ bit4 ^ bit5; 
}`

Given this hash function, following is the key-hash pair:

```
key       hash
0x0       0
0x1       1
0x2       1
0x3       0
0x4       0
0x5       1
0x6       1
0x7       0
0x8       1
....
```

So given this hash function, can you find the $n^{th}$ key that has a hash 0 in $O(1)$ (i.e. constant time) with the first key starting at 0x0?

For example, for n = 2, key = 0x3, for n = 4, key = 0x7 ...

The hash function given above is a toy example. The actual hash function that I have is XORing bits 0,1,6,7,10,13,14,15,16,18 of the key (i.e. the real hash function is more complicated).

I need solution to this problem for my project really badly. I need to be able to find the $n^{th}$ key in as few mathematical operations as possible as my code is very performance sensitive.

If O(1) is not possible, what is the next best possible solution? I currently can only think of doing brute force, with finding hash for all keys from 0x0 to 2n - 1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = hash\_function(x)$, for some $x$ in the input space.

$hash\_function$ returns a bit form at least $2^{18}$ space, 18-bit, or

$$hash\_function: 2^{18} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$$

There are $\approx 2^{17}$ values mapping 1 and $\approx 2^{17}$
 mapping 0, if we assume that your hash is uniformly random.

- To find the pre-image is impossible. Once you find a value $x' = hash\_function(y)$, you cannot determine $x = x'$ or $x \neq x'$.
- second preimage has $\approx 2^{17}$ solutions. Finding one is very easy, take a random value and test it, if not take another randomly. The problem is the values are not going to help you.

Comment: Can you explain your implementation? I don't need a popcount() algorithm, it is provided by the hardware as an instruction. But what I do need it to find out the nth key with a specific hash (In O(1)). What you are telling me is how to find the hash of a single key. FYI, for finding a hash of a single key I am doing exactly what you are doing (Except I use hardware provided popcount())

Comment: What is nth key? are trying to implement a hash table? So the nth key is one of the $2^32$ key set?

Comment: Nth key is the nth key, starting from 0, that has same hash for a given hash. For example, for hash fucntion hash = h(key), if this is the key to hash mapping (key, hash) -> (0, 1), (1, 7), (2, 6), (3, 1) ... then for hash = 1, the 1st key is '0' and 2nd key is '3' and so on.

Comment: @SakshamJain my problem, I don't see a chain here.  Could you explicitly show the chain.

Comment: If we look at the given example:
`/* This hash function calculates hash based on XORing bits 0,1,3,4 of the key */
 bool hash_function(uint64_t key) {
    bool bit0 = (key >> 0) & 0x1;
    bool bit1 = (key >> 1) & 0x1;
    bool bit3 = (key >> 3) & 0x1;
    bool bit4 = (key >> 4) & 0x1;
    return bit0 ^ bit1 ^ bit4 ^ bit5; 
}`

Given this hash function, following is the key-hash pair:
`
key       hash
0x0       0
0x1       1
0x2       1
0x3       0
0x4       0
0x5       1
0x6       1
0x7       0
0x8       1
`
Here the 3rd Key for hash 1 is 0x5

Comment: If you are asking what is the pattern, that is my question.

Comment: @SakshamJain there are no chain in your example, just a lookup right? Each of the hashes is independent.

Comment: Yes. No chain. Lookup based on hash. But hashed of key are correlated by the hash function so there is pattern.

Comment: I, really, don't get it. You have $\mathcal{O}(1)$ hash algorithm and you want to make it faster?

Comment: No, I want to do the reverse. Given a hash function and a specific hash, find the key (the nth key). Please take another look at the description and the provided example.

Comment: so you want the pre-image or secondary pre-image attack.